# Angular CLI class file imports must be capitalized - why?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created a simple class in Angular using the CLI starter. When I imported the file and tried to use the class it didn't work. It was basically just an empty object being returned. I played around trying to figure out what the issue was and decided to capitalize the file name from store to Store in the import and it works.

***Class:***

```
export class Store {
  private cards: Object = {};
  private previousId: number = -1;

  private addCard(card: Card) {
    this.cards[card['id']] = card;
    return card['id'];
  }

  public getCard(id) {
    return this.cards[id];
  }

  public create(text: string) {
    // Do some stuff...
  }
}
```

***Class Usage:***

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getColumsConfig();
  this.store = new Store();
  console.log(this.store);
}
```

***After newing up the class I got an empty object:***

[image]

***I named the file store.ts, and I initially imported it as follows:***

```
import { Store } from '../../services/store';
```

***I then renamed the import to the following and it worked:***

```
import { Store } from '../../services/Store';
```

[image]

Does anyone know why? I tried to google this but had no success.
File named in IED:

[image]

Comment: Well that string (the source for the `import`) is basically a file name (minus the ".js"); what OS are you using? Perhaps the actual file has a capitalized name, and your OS has case-sensitive file names (like Linux or MacOS).

Comment: Im using Mac. But I created the file with small caps just like every other file I created in the project and this is the only instance when importing that its requiring me to capitalize the file name.

Comment: Well if the actual file that gets imported really is called "store.js" (which should be easy to verify), then I have no clue. Hopefully somebody more Angular than me will know.

Comment: I updated the post with an image of the file system from the IDE.

Comment: Why `import { Card }` instead of `import { Store }` ?

Comment: Because the file also contains a model that is being exported.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because I forgot the add the store service to the providers array.